# materializecss Checkbox not displaying in aspx site

Tags: css, materialize

I have set up materialize css in my project, however the local copy does not appear to work with checkboxes or radio buttons. I am not sure why this would be the case. When I use the CDN version everything works as expected.

Here is a slightly messy .master file.

```
  <%-- Font Awesome --%>
    <link href="~/includes/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <%-- Includes the Materialize CSS --%>
    <%--<link href="~/includes/css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet" />--%>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

        <%-- Jquery because I need it still, hope to remove this in the future --%>
   <%-- <script type="text/javascript"
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src=<%= ResolveUrl("~/includes/js/materialize.js") %>></script>--%>

     <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

[image: Folder tree setup]

I don't really want to call a third party CDN forever in this case.I feel I am missing something simple here and that I am being an idiot.

Comment: IT appears to only be the .css page, I will update